# Rank of symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B, C, D$ are symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices with complex coefficients. How to prove that $\exists ~ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{C}$, such that they not equal to zero at the same time and 
$$\alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C + \delta D$$ has rank at most 1.

UPD. I have idea that because of summing up four matrices of size $3 \times 3$ every row is linear dependent (for example $\alpha A_{j}, \beta B_{j}, \gamma C_{j}, \delta D_{j}$ are linear dependent). However, I don't know how to do next steps.

Comment: ...and/or what are your thoughts on approaches to proving this?  and/or Why is this question important to you?  and/or Where did you encounter the question? and/or Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Comment: @amWhy I added my ideas on this problem.

Comment: @Arthur I added my ideas on this problem.

Comment: Consider SVD of A